# File does not convert Image format in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public IActionResult GenerateFile(string qrText)
{
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrText, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
    string fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4);
    qrCodeData.SaveRawData("wwwroot/qrr/file-" + fileGuid + ".jpg", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);

    QRCodeData qrCodeData1 = new QRCodeData("wwwroot/qrr/file-" + fileGuid + ".jpg", QRCodeData.Compression.Uncompressed);
    QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData1);
    Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
    return View(BitmapToBytes(qrCodeImage));
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the error you get ? What is expected and what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: It could work well in my project.It save as .jpg file in www/qrr folder and display to the view successfully.Which do you fail?What is your error message?